# how to refresh current page while doing pull to refresh (LiquidPullToRefresh) in Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, pull-to-refresh

am using bloc method for home screen. I want to do pull to refresh in home screen...
I tired too many ways not getting solution...could you please suggest some solution.

In side onrefresh() I added few changes

```
1 . BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => OttGetAllMovie(httpClient: http.Client())
          ..add(FeedsFetched(widget.title, "homePage")),
        //child: HomePage(),
        child: OttGetHomeInnerCatPage(
            wtitle: widget.title, mixpanelinner: widget.mixpanel),
      )

2.    _feedsBloc.add(FeedsFetched(widget.wtitle, "homePage"));

3. setState(() {
     _feedsBloc.add(FeedsFetched(widget.wtitle, "homePage"));
 BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => OttGetAllMovie(httpClient: http.Client())
          ..add(FeedsFetched(widget.title, "homePage")),
        //child: HomePage(),
        child: OttGetHomeInnerCatPage(
            wtitle: widget.title, mixpanelinner: widget.mixpanel),
      )

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

While

this seems to be the method you're using to fetch data

```
OttGetAllMovie(httpClient: http.Client())
          ..add(FeedsFetched(widget.title, "homePage")),
```

Wrap your body in liquid pull to refresh

```
    LiquidPullToRefresh(
            key: _refreshIndicatorKey,  // key if you want to add
            onRefresh: ()async{
//cal your data source
               OttGetAllMovie(httpClient: http.Client())
              ..add(FeedsFetched(widget.title, "homePage")),
           }
            child: ListView(),      // scroll view
          );
```

Comment: I added everything as per your suggestion...but UI not reflect ..its showing old data only ..am using pageview . any idea ?

Comment: in you logs does it hit this event `FeedsFetched(widget.title, "homePage")` , or what event do you use to fetch data from your client

Comment: FeedsFetched(widget.title, "homePage") this event only I used for fetch data

Comment: try this, adding break points to any method called when you add event FeedsFetched and see whether it actually calls the methods.

Comment: yeah I checked with break point too...its working fine  till fetch data.UI only not reflect

Comment: might be how you are yielding states. add some code on what FeedsFetched does, including the states it yields